# Trigger Jquery UI Dialog with Jquery Form Plugin success callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using server side form validation to post a response (in html) to a form submitted using Ajax but more specifically with the http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started plugin.

I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog'
        });
    $('#bookingForm').ajaxForm({
        success: function() { 
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
            return false;
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

The Ajax submit fires, and the server returns a response but no jquery dialog.

Removing

```
autoOpen: false,
```

shows the dialog so I know that this part of the script is working.

> I have also tested the callback with an alert and it is also working.

Your help is appreciated.

Tim

Comment: Any errors on the page? Are you sure jQueryUI is being loaded correctly?

Comment: No errors in firebug or chrome developer tools, If I fire $dialog.dialog('open'); return false; on a button click function event handler it works. Or even easier just remove autoOpen: false and it loads right away.

Comment: Can you show how the submit is done? is it causing the page to reload?

Comment: Sorry, please disregard my last comment.

Comment: Is the success callback is called ? Have your tried adding a console.log or an alert prior to your dialog open ?

Comment: Hi, Yes the success callback is working. I just tested with an alert ('success') and it fired... I have a feeling I'm missing something with the ui dialog.

Answer (score 0):

is this about scope? the $dialog isn't available because it's inside a function

try

```
 var $dialog;
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
```